# C pointer arithmetics and expression evaluation

Tags: c, pointers, expression, pointer-arithmetic

I need help with evaluating this C code. In particular, I am not hundred percent sure about the last line:

```
#define uint unsigned int
#define ushort unsigned short

uint *contents; // 96 bytes long array
int uVar1;

// some code that messes around with contents and uVar1

*(ushort*)((uint)contents + 2) = uVar1;
```

I assume it to be equivalent with the following:

```
uint temp = (uint)contents;
temp = temp + 2;
ushort *temp2 = (ushort *)temp;
*temp2 = uVar1;
```

The code is a snippet of decompiled code. I need to do something logically equivalent in Java, where I use a `long[]` array for the `contents` variable.

Comment: [C++] Undefined behaviour.

Comment: Assuming little endian, I believe it sets the high bits of the first integer that `contents` points to.

Comment: You didn't ask a question or explain what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct that it's equivalent to that code. Which has undefined or implementation-dependent behavior.

Comment: @interjay They asked if the two snippets are equivalent

Comment: @Barmar If they have UB, they can't possibly be deemed equivalent.

Comment: There's no pointer arithmetic here, only integer arithmetic.

Comment: @ikegami No they didn't.

Comment: @ikegami They both have the same UB because of the equivalence.

Comment: @interjay, Fine, don't believe me. but that's what they asked.

Comment: @interjay Sorry, I updated the question.

Comment: The original code is probably something like `unsigned short contents[48]; contents[1] = uVar1;`

Comment: @Barmar, Re "*They both have the same UB because of the equivalence.*", No, UB means anything could happen. There's no guarantee it's always the same somethiing. The compiler could generate different code for both, and the generated code could have different effects.

Comment: @ikegami I mean they both violate the same constraints that result in them being UB.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: But since this isn't real code, but the result of decompiling assembly, all this is moot; it obviously will work on the implementation where the code came from.

Comment: Unless `contents` point anywhere, this code is nonsense. Where does it point and more importantly at what type? Please post a [mcve] or at least an actual copy paste of the actual code.

Comment: @Lundin The comment says some code that messes around with `contents` and `uVar1`. I thought that would imply that contents points to something and probably contains values `!= 0`. I do not know myself what `contents` contains exactly because, as mentioned, it is decompiled code and quite messy.

Comment: It matters a lot if it points at some other int variable, a chunk of malloc:ed memory, a static array etc etc. In some cases the code posted is definitely undefined behavior, in other cases perhaps not.

Comment: Also if this is decompiled code then whatever tool that did that is simply broken...

Comment: @Lundin It's output of Ghirda. We also tried it with Hex Rays but there the output was way messier with like 80 local variables, which made it nearly impossible to use it... Thats why I needed to use this one.